# What is the problem that gets worse after you try to solve it?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Example sentence - *This problem is a _____ which gets complicated every time you try to solve it.*

Is there such a word that represents a problem which will become worse if/when one tries to solve it?

Note - After seeing the comments and answers I'd like to add that this is not a can of worms or Pandora's box because it doesn't create a new problem but just worsens.

Example: Magic leaves protecting a fruit by enclosing it. Every time a leaf is touched, all the leaves close together further, that is more tight than before.

Comment: Your question lacks detail, could you describe a situation where attempting a solution has made it worse? Could you at least provide the context, why are you looking for such a word or idiom?

Comment: I believe that "mew problem" > "new problem".

Comment: I believe you're looking for the word 'relationship'

Comment: Fukushima Daiichi disaster appears to be such a situation. Can we use that as a "problem?" It's only getting worse despite… Well, It's not like Chernobyl where everyone just "walked away."

Comment: Regarding create new problems vs problem worsening, I agree with earlier comments that a specific example would help as often these are interchangeable. Maybe an idiom not specifically related to problems would do - spiraling out of control or positive-feedback loop.

Comment: "Chinese finger trap" as a figurative usage might come close.

Comment: There's some Australian colloquialisms that would work in this instance, though would be considered rather inappropriate here.

Comment: I would describe such a problem as *self-compounding*, which is just a fancier way of saying *self-worsening*. Or I'd reference Leia's jab at Tarkin and the Empire: "The more you tighten your grip, the more star systems will slip through your fingers."

Comment: "Quagmire" or "sticky situation" are probably the best and most current. "Tar baby" is good but rather dated. "Quicksand" is pretty good but that's more like a situation that's dangerous and final (sinking in quicksand) rather than just a mess. A quagmire or a sticky situation denotes something that's probably solvable but gets ugly if you mess with it.

Comment: In the computer field, this is known as a "[regex problem](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)".

Comment: Reminds me of stories of cutting starfish (sea star) in 2 to kill it, instead it make for 2 starfish.  IAC, not recommend method of sea star control.

Comment: *Hydra* is the best of the bunch below.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**can of worms**

> informal. a situation that causes a lot of problems for you when you start to deal with it:
>   *Corruption is a serious problem, but nobody has yet been willing to open up that can of worms.*
>   — [Cambridge Advanced Learner’s Dictionary & Thesaurus](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/can-of-worms)

Comment: Can of worms is for new problems arising out of a bad decision or action and not for the worsening of the original one. Your answer is inappropriate.

Comment: @User1234567890: Just FWIW, "inappropriate" is a fairly harsh word. It doesn't suit your desired use, fine, but "can of worms" was a reasonable answer to your originally-posed question. Frequently, a can of worms *is* a problem in the first place, we just choose not to address the problem because...it's a can of worms.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am not a native speaker. *Inappropriate* is among the few adjective I know for something wrong. I don't have enough words in my vocabulary to talk in that sense. I didn't mean to hurt or offend.

Comment: @User1234567890: I thought that might be the case; that's why I flagged it up for you. :-)

Comment: I believe there are more suitable (appropriate) answers than this excepted answer. All due respect.

Answer (score 34):

See **tar baby**.

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tar-baby)

> A difficult problem that is only aggravated by attempts to solve it.

Comment: The original meaning is a good fit, but beware of the other meaning, which is a racial slur.

Comment: Also: *sticky situation*.

Comment: @DavidK: I think "tar pit" would work, and convey the intended meaning.

Comment: @PeterCordes That could be an answer. When I read "tar pit" I think of prehistoric animals trapped in the famous La Brea Tar Pits in California. Fred Brooks famously used "tar pit" as a metaphor for the difficulties of developing large software systems: "The more you fight it, the deeper you sink!"

Comment: @DavidK: Apparently "hard problem" is already an accepted meaning for Tar Pit.  I added an answer with that.

Comment: @DavidK What other meaning?  I've never heard "tar baby" used as a racial slur.  (I've heard people talking about it as one, as you are here, but I've never actually seen the term *used*.  So I have to wonder where the idea comes from.)

Comment: @MasonWheeler See http://www.cbsnews.com/news/romney-apologizes-for-tar-baby/ -- you may not agree with the beliefs described in that article, but they exist and (in the US at least) should be reckoned with. This does not mean you can never write the words "tar baby"--after all, Toni Morrison used this as the title of a novel. (As for actual _use_ of the term as an intentional slur, that's the sort of thing that would tend not to be spoken in polite company by thoughtful people, and likewise not to make it into print, so specific evidence would naturally be hard to come by.)

Comment: @DavidK Yeah, I think that was exactly the context in which I heard of the idea that "tar baby" was a racial slur.  As I'd never heard the term used that way before, nor have I heard anyone making such a claim unconnected to that particular incident involving Mitt Romney, I personally find it far more likely that it's a manufactured political controversy that someone came up with to make Mitt Romney look bad.  (Heaven knows that happens often enough to any politician of any prominence!)

Comment: @MasonWheeler Toni Morrison mentioned in a 1995 interview that this was something "that white people call black children, black girls, as I recall." So the controversy definitely goes back further than that. The [Oxford Dictionaries' definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/tar-baby) traces the use as a racial slur to the 1940s.

Answer (score 33):

**Hydra-Headed problem**. The [Lernaean Hydra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lernaean_Hydra) was a sticky problem for Heracles. It regrew two heads each time one was lopped off.

Comment: Just "hydra" would work.

Comment: @Simon It was the *heads* that would double, not the *Hydra* herself.

Comment: @Constant'sErik Yes, the heads double, but the Hydra as a whole remains a problem that worsens with every attempt to solve it.

Comment: @Timbo It was the heads that were attacking. The necks were doubling every cut head. The rest of the Hydra just provided life. The Hydra's body wasn't getting bigger and bigger. Instead, the heads were the problem actually *worsening* when someone tried to solve it (Heracles).

Answer (score 15):

Something that is occasionally used metaphorically in this sense is **quicksand**:

> a situation that is dangerous and difficult to escape from - [merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quicksand)

Comment: Also: *quagmire*.

Comment: On quicksands, the more you try to escape, the more you sink. (might be be true in real life, but it illustrate the situation greatly)

Comment: "Quagmire" is often used to describe political situations where it seems to just get worse whatever you do, and no good outcome is in sight.

Comment: Giggidy... giggidy

Answer (score 15):

*Tar pit* is similar to *Tar baby*, but is a simpler metaphor to understand.  The simple and obvious meaning is that touching the problem will get you stuck in it / to it.  Apparently this is an existing usage of the term.

---

> Tar pit
>
> 1. a hollow in which natural tar accumulates by seepage.
> 2. **a complicated or difficult situation or problem.** "the tar pit of municipal poverty"

[from google's definition](https://www.google.ca/search?q=tar%20pit)

---

BTW, Tar baby is a reference to a fictional character that some people won't have heard of.  If you're talking to people that probably have heard of the [Tar Baby story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar-Baby), then it might be an even better choice.

Tar pit also avoids the [racist interpretation of Tar baby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar-Baby#Racist_interpretation) that apparently exists.

Answer (score 13):

I have heard situations in which every "solution" causes more problems referred to as a [*quagmire*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/quagmire):

> noun
>   1. An area of miry or boggy ground whose surface yields under the tread; a bog.
>   2. A situation from which extrication is very difficult: a quagmire of financial indebtedness.
>   3. Anything soft or flabby.

For example, see this [George Soros quote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/August_12):

> No external power, no terrorist organization, can defeat us. But we can defeat ourselves by getting caught in a quagmire.

Answer (score 10):

An instance of a [**bottomless pit**](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/bottomless_pit) (meaning 4)

> > an entity or problem which consumes seemingly endless resources.

or figuratively a **black hole**. There is a [StackExchange illustration for a bottomless pit in a finite universe, based on Gabriel's horn](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/15794/20149), an interesting mathematical object:

[image: Gabriel's horn]

Answer (score 9):

A [Gordian Knot](http://www.britannica.com/topic/Gordian-knot). This suggests an intractable problem that can be solved by drastic action or innovative thinking (because Alexander the Great solved the Gordian Knot by cutting it with his sword).

Comment: The Gordian Knot was severed (or otherwise untied) by Alexander the Great, not Hercules. Even the link you provide says as much.

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed.

Answer (score 8):

I would vote for "Wicked Problem" - which is not just a qualifier, but has been used in a more precise sense, especially in Social Policy Planning, as detailed in the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wicked_problem).

The same entry also provides a comprehensive bibliography and points to related terms.

Comment: "Wicked" in this technical sense is a very good answer, but the fine implications are not likely to be widely understood. (I only heard this definition on a course in Project Risk Management.)

Comment: @AAT - yes, I know, this is why I added the Wikipedia link, most people would probably not know about the technical meaning, unfortunately.

Comment: As I said, it is a very good answer! I agree also with your "unfortunately": let's agree to do our best to spread the word!

Answer (score 7):

It's a [Gordian Knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordian_Knot), in that pulling on the rope (to try to undo it) just makes the knot tighter.

Alexander the Great gave that a new meaning (by cutting through it with his sword), but that (an untractable problem made worse by trying to solve it) is what it used to be before he showed up.

Comment: [Already answered](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/333274/32913).

Answer (score 5):

You could use *aggravate*, the second definition in [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aggravate) defines aggravate as:-

> to make worse, more serious, or more severe :  intensify unpleasantly

So as per your example: 'This problem is aggravated every time you try to resolve it.'

Another word you could use is *exasperate*: [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exasperate) lists this as *obsolete*
though it is the first word I thought of after reading your question.

Comment: simple! but that's it

Answer (score 5):

It's a long expression / saying but it means exactly to find oneself in a worse predicament, or make a bad situation worse.

> **out of the frying pan into the fire**
>
> Fig. from a bad situation to a worse situation. (*Typically: *get* ~; *go* ~; *jump* ~.)
>   <sub>*[McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+the+frying+pan+into+the+fire)*</sub>

Answer (score 2):

A [conundrum](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conundrum) is a problem that apparently has no solution, as more complications appear as aspects of it are solved.

> 2a: a question or problem having only a conjectural answer.
> b: an intricate and difficult problem

Answer (score 2):

You could also tangentially consider a ***minefield***:

> a subject, situation, etc, beset with hidden problems
>   <sub>*[Collins English Dictionary - Complete & Unabridged 2012 Digital Edition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/minefield)*</sub>

This is generally used to describe a problem that will be a lot more complex to solve than it looks, often looking unassumingly simple.

Answer (score 1):

A bureaucratic / procedurally descriptive phrase is the
***[one step forward, two steps back](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/one+step+forward,+two+steps+back)*** idiom. 
This seems fairly self-explanatory; it is defined in The Free Dictionary as

> something that you say which means every time you make progress,
>   something bad happens which causes you to be in a worse situation
>   than you were to begin with

Answer (score 0):

This fits to a degree:

- No win scenario

[Kobayashi_Maru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobayashi_Maru)

Although your example *might* have a solution which is as yet unknown.

Answer (score 0):

I would try [**paradox**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paradox)

It is commonly defined as a problem that made up of two opposite things and that seems impossible but is actually true or possible.

Thus by your example when attempting to open a leaf ball, it closes.  Or in the example of quick sand, the more you struggle, the more difficult it is to escape.

Answer (score 0):

Apart, perhaps, from 'gordian knot' as has already been suggested, I can't think of any word or compound with an established definition that exactly fits the bill.

So, it's been mentioned already but, to me, ***conundrum*** would work best in the sentence given

> This problem is a conundrum which gets [more?] complicated every time you try to solve it.

Conundrum, of course, means:

> Any puzzling question or problem; an enigmatical statement. - *OED*

Which, on it's own, doesn't really fit the exact requirement that the OP has posted.

However, I would argue that, in current usage, it is filling the gap.

A quick check on Google News returns these on the first page:

- > White House Countdown: The Ryan Conundrum
- > The Afghan conundrum
- > British farmers face conundrum: the hearts says ‘Leave’ the EU but the head says ‘Remain’
- > Promising Gene Therapies Pose Million-Dollar Conundrum
- > A political conundrum

In each of these cases the 'conundrum' is an issue or question that can be described quickly, often in a single, brief paragrapgh, but which is complicated and, often apparently unsolvable.

Answer (score 0):

Such a problem is **snowballing** or is experiencing a **snowball effect**

[McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/snowball)

> Figurative. [for something] to become larger or more serious by growing like a snowball being rolled. This whole problem is snowballing into a crisis very rapidly. The argument soon snowballed into a full-blown riot.