# Medicating Uvula resulted in making the tongue fall out

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests, semantics, idiom-meaning

> **Medicating Uvula  resulted  in making   the  tongue  fall out**

*The proverb means  sometimes   remedying  a  simple  problem  may  turn  out  to  be a  different  problem  of    great  magnitude*

I  would  like  to  know  the  equivalent  problem  in  English.

I  believe  that  it  is  not  a  duplicate  of   the  previous  post  because  in the  post  the  Post  The  OP was  saying  that  the  situation  was  getting  worse  every  time  being rectified.But  the  proverb  I posted  does  not  mean it.Trying  to  solve  a  problem  resulted  in  a  some  other  problem  of   great  magnitude  and  danger.Besides,
**My  proverb  is  a  literal  translation of  a  Telugu  proverb**  which  may imply  that  we  must  be  very  careful about
 remeding  a  situation  otherwise  it  might  lead  to  a  different  consequence  which  might  be  fatal.It  does  not  mean  that  the  same situation is  getting  worsened  as  a result  of  medication  or  the  metophorical use  of the  same  problem getting  more complicated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the problem that gets worse after you try to solve it?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/333211/what-is-the-problem-that-gets-worse-after-you-try-to-solve-it) and the closed duplicate [proverb for {when} solving a problem creates a bigger one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/388189/proverb-for-solving-a-problem-creates-a-bigger-one/388193#388193).

Comment: Tangentially, you've got multiple spaces between words (you should use one), and none after punctuation (where there should be).

Comment: I agree the duplicate isn't right. [This one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/388189/proverb-for-solving-a-problem-creates-a-bigger-one/388191#388191) that Edwin also linked to is better - 'out of the pan and into the fire' has exactly the meaning of your edit.

Comment: @ Marcellothearcane.I agree with  you.There  are  punctuation errors But  the  proverb  is  not  a  duplicate.It  is  an original and  folk  idiom  in my  mother-tongue.I dont know  how  the  idiom  could  be  a  duplicate

Answer (score 0):

One proverb close in meaning is: ***[the cure is worse than the disease](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the_cure_is_worse_than_the_disease)***

> The medical treatment for an illness produces a worse net result than the illness does (or threatens a non-negligible risk of doing so), especially via adverse effects.
> *(figuratively) The solution or proposed solution to a problem produces a worse net result than the problem does (or threatens a non-negligible risk of doing so), especially via unintended consequences.*

(Wiktionary)

Comment: A search from your suggested answer immediately reveals that this is a duplicate.