# Is there a phrase that describes a problem that becomes more and more complicated the further you investigate/look into it?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a phrase that describes a problem whose complexity starts to increase exponentially, either because the problem is recursive, the definitions/conditions of the problem interlink with themselves, or it turns out that it's connected to a great many other issues, and changing one changes all the others in turn.

This phrase would be useful when, say, discussing how to solve a simple, harmless, trivial little bug in some software...that now has eight people standing around debating business logic and corollaries to corollaries and exceptions to exceptions.

Phrases that are close, but not what I'm looking for:

- "Tip of the iceberg" could be used later on when describing the original difficulty, since it would become much worse later, but the rest of the situation wasn't originally an issue or complicated, and only by investigating the original, simple issue did the full complication arise.
- "Can of worms": the rest of the difficulty isn't inherently a problem; the original, minor issue is the only part that's an actual problem, and the rest of the complication is created by trying to solve it.
- "Cure is worse than the disease": it's not that the solution is bad or undesirable, but that the original problem was far more complicated than it first appeared.
- "Gordian knot" describes a problem that is already complicated known to be difficult; what I'm looking for is a situation that seems simple or even easy until you try to solve it.

Comment: Would **mares nest** work?

Comment: You can say something like "It seemed simple enough at first but the deeper we got into it, the more it became a mares nest.".    You may not find a term that conveys the notion of *becoming* more complex the deeper in you get.

Comment: "entangling problems" ?

Comment: Related phrases that I don't think are quite what you're looking for "through the looking glass", "down the rabbit hole", and [Heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug). (This last one is very close, but it's even more specific than what you're asking for - it's a bug that becomes more complicated by the virtue of the observed/bugged behavior changing when you attempt to debug it.)

Comment: Interesting question.  You are in a way describing the other side of Alice's looking glass.  But that would not do for your purpose.  You could call the problem labyrinthine.  When people enter a labyrinth (or maze) it seems simpler than it really is.  In the novel 'The Name of the Rose' the solution of the death that takes place at the beginning of the novel, the English monk William Baskerville  gradually unravels a murder mystery that does indeed get more complex as he unravels it.  There is a labyrinthine library  in it which hold the key.  But too few are familiar with it for it to work.

Comment: "Can of worms" seems to describe what you want. A problem that seems simple until you try and solve it and then you find lots of hidden complexities.

Comment: *Until we looked under the hood* is a phrase I've heard used in business consulting referring to problems which seemed simple on the surface....*until we looked under the hood* and which point the problems metastasize

Comment: I wouldn't use Labyrinthine, since, like Rube Goldberg Machine, it doesn't capture the feeling of an unexpected increase in complexity. "Under the hood" isn't bad, but it feels more like a description of where/how the problem came about, not the difficulty of the problem itself or change thereof. "Through the looking glass" is the closest I've heard yet, just because it implies a descent into madness or absurdity—it's not perfect, but it's close.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the problem that gets worse after you try to solve it?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/333211/what-is-the-problem-that-gets-worse-after-you-try-to-solve-it):  **tar baby**: A difficult problem that is only aggravated by attempts to solve it [Oxford, ex ODO] / hydra / out of the frying pan into the fire

Comment: No, though it gets vaguely near. The distinction is that this problem isn't getting worse because of your attempted solution, it's just that investigating it reveals the complexity that was already there, if unrealized.

Comment: That's contrary to 'it's connected to a great many other issues, and changing one changes all the others in turn'.

Comment: A common interpretation of the expression "deceptively simple" is something that initially appears to be simple but then reveals its complexity.

Comment: Borges' story *The Garden of Forking Paths* has relevance here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Garden_of_Forking_Paths

Answer (score 0):

It could be described as a "**Rube Goldberg**" problem in search of a simple solution.

[Dictionary.com - Rube Goldberg](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/rube-goldberg)

Comment: Thanks, but his isn't what I'm looking for, since a Rube Goldberg machine is usually apparently complicated, and the issue isn't that I have a complicated problem that needs a simple solution, it's that I had a (seemingly) simple problem that's become more and more complicated as I learn more about it.

Comment: I get it, but my answer is understandable - the Rube Goldberg aspect describes the problem (increasing in complexity) by contrast the solution - which follows the problem - is simple. Sorry it doesn't make sense to you. Par for the course on SE.